# Laravel - Executing command in controller, track progress

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a system where the user can download a composer package with the click of a button. The installation goes fine and the package gets installed but there is no way to track the progress of the command. I want to track the progress and show it in a progress bar but I don't quite know how to?

**Links**

```
<a href="{{ route('install_package') }}" class="badge badge-light fa-1x">Install</a>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<a href="{{ route('uninstall_package') }}" class="badge badge-light fa-1x">Uninstall</a>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('package/install', 'PackageController@install')->name('install_package');
Route::get('package/uninstall', 'PackageController@uninstall')->name('uninstall_package');
```

**Controller**

```
public function install()
    {
        $package = new Process("composer require rainieren/visitors");
        $package->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
        $package->run();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        $package = new Process("composer remove rainieren/visitors");
        $package->setWorkingDirectory(base_path());
        $package->run();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to find the size of the package? Or the remaining time from Composer directly? If yes, then you can start a long polling "session" and calculate how much time is renaming compared to how much time it took to download the already downloaded bytes. You can achieve this by starting a ajax request, and adding something like `while ($downloading) { //respond with remaining time }`, then in AJAX you have to keep repeating the request each time a response is received until a downloaded flag is returned by the server (e.g. `while($downloading) {...} return 'downloaded';`)

Comment: The `Process` class can be given a callback which will receive chunked output which would normally show in the console. If you were to combine that callback with AJAX polling or websockets, you'll be albe to show the progress of the command being executed. The [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output) offers a good explanation on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` or `shell_exec` php functions.
E.g.

```
exec('composer require rainieren/visitors');
// or
shell_exec('composer require rainieren/visitors');
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Or you can do like this:

```
$phpFinder = new PhpExecutableFinder();

        if($phpBin = $phpFinder->find()) {

            $cmdLine = "$phpBin ".base_path('lib/composer/composer.phar').' require rainieren/visitors';
            $process = new Process(str_replace('\\','/',$cmdLine),base_path($this->getDistPath()));
            $process->setTimeout(0);
            $process->mustRun(function($type,$line){
                // get output if needed
            });
        }
```

Don't depend on a global composer install, the path is reachable within the project base folder.

P.s. [PhpExecutableFinder](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/PhpExecutableFinder.php)